# What is the Powershell equivalent to C's argv[0]?

Tags: powershell

That is to say - how can I get the name of the called script from within said script? For example, if I do this:

```
.\foobar.ps1 -param1 10 -param2 20
```

How would I get the string 'foobar.ps1'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) that provides this information: [$PSCommandPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#pscommandpath).

This gives the full path to the script, but if you want just the file name, you can use [Split-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7.2) to get just that part:

`Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Leaf`

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!